# Bellmans equation and existence of optimal policy for MDPs

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I'm trying to understand the proof of existence of an optimal policy from this question
[Why is there always at least one policy that is better than or equal to all other policies?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207780/why-is-there-always-at-least-one-policy-that-is-better-than-or-equal-to-all-othe)
by Lovelris.

-

First, here's my attempt at a proof, which is shorter than the linked question, and so perhaps there's something wrong, or it proves something different, or I might be using a wrong definition at some point in my proof. I think it explains the first step in the linked proof in more detail, but I don't really see why the later steps are needed. I would appreciate if someone checked my proof, and maybe compared it to the linked one.

Suppose we have a discounted MDP, and assume for simplicity that we have a finite amount of states, actions, and rewards, that are only dependent on the state. We would like to show that there exists an optimal decision (stationary) policy $\pi^*$, i.e. it is true that $V^{\pi^*}(s) = V^*(s)$ for all states $s \in S$, where $V^*(s) = \max_{\pi} V^{\pi}(s)$. Here $\max_{\pi} V^{\pi}(s)$ is clearly well defined and exists (though the $\pi$ can be different for different states).

Consider any $s \in S$. Then using Bellman's equation for $V^{\pi}(s)$ we have
\begin{align*}
V^* (s) &= \max_{\pi} V^{\pi}(s)\\
&= max_{a \in A} \: max_{\pi, \pi(s) = a} [r(s) + \gamma \sum_{s'} P_{s,a}(s') V^{\pi}(s')]\\
&\leq max_{a \in A} [r(s) + \gamma \sum_{s'} P_{s,a}(s') V^{*}(s')]\\
\end{align*}

Define $\tilde \pi$ as the policy that maximizes the above inequality, i.e.
$$ \tilde \pi (s) = \arg \max_a [r(s) + \gamma \sum_{s'} P_{s,a}(s') V^{*}(s')]$$

Then we have
$$ V^* \leq [r(s) + \gamma \sum_{s'} P_{s,\tilde \pi (s)}(s') V^{*}(s')]$$

Denoting the vector $V^*$ for $(V^*(s_1),...,V^*(s_n))$, and similarly for $V^{\tilde \pi}$ and $r$, and denoting the matrix corresponding to $\gamma P_{s,\tilde \pi(s)}$ by $B$, we have that

$$ V^* \leq r + BV^* \; i.e. (I-B)V^* \leq r$$
$$ V^{\tilde \pi} = r + BV^{\tilde \pi} \; i.e. (I-B)V^{\tilde \pi} = r$$

and so

$(I-B)(V^{\tilde \pi} - V^*) \geq 0$. Because $(I-B)^{-1}$ exists and $u \geq 0$ implies $(I-B)^{-1} (u) \geq u \geq 0$ ( intuitively $(I-B)^{-1}(u)$ is really just the expected payoff given policy $\tilde \pi$ and reward vector $u$, so clearly if $u \geq 0$, we have that the expected payoff is non negative), and so $(V^{\tilde \pi} - V^*) \geq 0$, which shows that $V^{\tilde \pi} = V^*$

-

The basic idea is quite simple and is maybe easier to see in the case of $V^\pi(s) < Q^\pi(s,a)$. Here denote  $\pi' = \pi$ for all states except $s$, for which $\pi'(s) = a$. Symbolically we then have $v = r + Av < r + Bv$ and $v' = r + Bv'$, where $A$ is the matrix corresponding to the policy of $\pi$ and $B$ to that of $\pi'$, and $v'$ is just the solution to the equation. In this scenario $B$ is $A$ with one row exchanged. Note - here $v < r + Bv$ means that $v \leq r + Bv$ in all components, and $v < r + Bv$ in at least in component.

So again as above, we have that $(I-B)(v' - v) > 0$, and so $v' > v$, meaning that if $V^\pi(s) < Q^\pi(s,a)$, then there exists a policy $\pi'$ such that $V^{\pi'}(s) > V^{\pi}(s)$.

By an argument of similar type, if we now observe how the other components of $V^{\pi'}$ look, I think we can also show that $V^{\pi'}(s') \geq V^{\pi}(s')$ for all the other states too (we can "ignore" the first column of $A$ because we're assuming the $V^{\pi'}(s_1)$ is fixed). So if $V^\pi(s) < Q^\pi(s,a)$, then changing the action in this state, will only improve the resulting values. But I'm not too sure about this.

Comment: I've only fully understood the second part of your question, where you explain the "basic idea". I think the problem with your line of reasoning is that in the Bellman Equation for the `pi'` policy, you do not change the reward `r` into `r'`. Choosing a different action `a` when at state `s` will alter the corresponding reward `r`, too. In fact, that's why the problem in interesting...choosing an action that is sub-optimal immediately might in fact be optimal in the long term.

Comment: Also, how are `B` and `A` dependent on the policy? Aren't they a property of the environment? Correct me if I'm wrong, but they represent the probabilities of going from state-action pair `(s, a)` to state `s'`, right?